# how to solve the incompatible when using IF ELSE statement in Android studio?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-studio

when I created the the (EditText) fields a , b and c ,I let it's type as a number (android:inputType="number"), then when I tried to write the following code I got a hint told me that there is an incompatible .

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             if(!"".equals(a.getText())
             &&!"".equals(b.getText())
             &&!"".equals(c.getText())) {

                              double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
                              double b1 = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());
                              double c1 = Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString());

                              Double r = b1 * c1 / a1;
                              result.setText(r.toString());
                          }

                          else{
                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not A Real Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }

                          }
        });
```

Comment: use `android:digits = "1234567890."` instead, parse it to `String` using `toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text from an edittext, you need to do .getText().toString(). Simply doing .getText() will give you an Editable object, and not the text.

So add ".toString()" to all your .getText() functions, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Glad i could help. Please accept/upvote my answer if you found it satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(!"".equals(a.getText())
         &&!"".equals(b.getText())
         &&!"".equals(c.getText()))
```

you need to call

```
   if(!"".equals(a.getText().toString())
         &&!"".equals(b.getText().toString())
         &&!"".equals(c.getText().toString()))
```